# Error while creating the cloud function (agent-template-banking)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

**SOLVED**
I have been trying to use Google Cloud's Rapid Response Virtual Agent Templates. While creating the cloud function, I'm getting this error:

> Deployment failure: Function failed on loading user code. Error
>   message: File index.js or function.js that is expected to define
>   function doesn't exist in the root directory.

I uploaded the dialogflow-fulfillment zip file and chose runtime as Node.js 8

Please Help.

Comment: Could you provide the file structure of the zip file? The root of the file should have contained a file index.js or function.js which according to the error message it is not found.

Comment: I was uploading the zip file of the folder which contained index.js and package.json. These two files should be zipped together directly no need of folder. The error is resolved now. Thank You. @EnriqueDelValle

Comment: Nice, the recommendation is that you post the solution to the issue that you faced as a response